# How to block access to Subversion server for clients below 1.6 version

Tags: svn, apache, http, tortoisesvn

My Subversion server access is through Apache HTTP. For instance, I don't want TortoisSVN not at version 1.6 and above be able to access it. The blockage should happen for any client not at 1.6 or above.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this E-Mail from Stefan Küng](http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2009-08/0331.shtml) (one of the Authors of TortoiseSVN), there are two ways of doing this: Using the `USER_AGENT` in Apache, and the `capabilities` parameter in a Subversion hook.

Both ways look doable but tricky.

The Apache variant would require changes in `httpd.conf` (or wherever you define access to the repository) but it's going to be hard to build a regular expression that checks the `USER_AGENT` string for a *version number larger than x*. While that is certainly possible to do, I have no idea how.

The `capabilities` parameter uses a capability specific to 1.5 (merging) in [this example](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.pre1.5clients) - whether there is a `capability` in 1.6 that you can put to use to distinguish the version number, I do not know - you'd have to find out.